# Can't find work done in Git branch after checking out another branch

Tags: git

I was on the master branch, and I ran `git checkout -b ui`. Did tons of work over the course of a week, at the end of which I ran:

```
git add .
git commit -am 'ui'

git checkout master
git merge ui
git push
```

I then switched to a branch that I had worked on previously- `git checkout uploads` - At which point every thing I had done in the ui branch was lost.  It's not listed in `git log`, and `git reset --hard HEAD^` takes me back to the branch prior to the 'ui' branch.  How does this happen?

I was able to recover most of it by looking through reflog and reverting to the 'ui' commit, but I wonder what causes this to happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It wasn't lost, it's just that when you switch branches in git (with `git checkout`) your working tree is completely changed to have the files on that branch.  If you run:

```
git branch
```

... you should see `master`, `ui` and `uploads` all listed.

If you want to see the log for the `ui` branch, you should run:

```
git log ui
```

The reason that `git reset --hard HEAD^` moved you back to the commit on `master` before you merged `ui` is that your merge commit (where `master` was at) has two parents:

1. `master` before the merge
2. `ui` before the merge

When you add a single `^` to a commit name, that takes you back to the *first* parent - to refer to the second parent, you would use `HEAD^2`.  However, I guess that you don't really want to do `git reset --hard` here to change where `master` is.  (In any case, that's a command that should be used with care, since it will throw away changes that aren't committed.)

Anyway, all the changes that you did on the `ui` branch are now merged into `master`, so if you're happy with what you did there you shouldn't need to worry about the `ui` branch any more.  [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill)'s answer suggests a couple of courses of action if what you now want is to make sure that your `uploads` branch contains all that work.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense then.  Kind of freaked out when I re-loaded a file and all the additions were gone. I wasn't expecting it as I'm quite new to git. thanks

Comment: @aperture: indeed, it's most surprising the first time you see your working tree completely change after a `git checkout` - even more so if you're working in a repository where people store **completely** different working trees on different branches of the same repository :)  As a more general point, once changes are committed in git, it makes it very difficult for you to lose them, so committing regularly is good practice...

Answer (score 3):

Everything you've described is as expected. It sounds like you were surprised that your work on the `ui` branch did not appear when you switched to the `uploads` branch. That makes sense, because the `ui` work did not exist at the time you created `uploads`. You can take two approaches here:

1. Merge `master` into `uploads`: `git merge master`
2. Rebase `uploads` onto `master`: `git rebase master`

Both these commands would be run on the `uploads` branch.